# How to write PHP code (using prepared statements) to return rows from MySQL DB when some input parameters use a value 'all' as wildcard?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, wildcard

I'm a PHP novice and am working to create a webform using PHP and MySQL (I have some experience with MySQL but at most am at the intermediate level). The front-end webform lets the user enter values of the following 4 parameters: genre, composer, instrument, and ensemble. Each of these parameters can either take a proper name (e.g., "classical" for genre, "violin" for instrument, etc.), or a value called "all". If "all", then the MySQL database will return all the rows of that parameter or parameters (filtered, of course, on the other parameters that are not "all"). I also want to write the PHP codes using prepared statements.

So, I wrote the following PHP code:

```
// The variables take the values entered by user in the webform
$genre = htmlspecialchars($_POST['genre']);
$composer = htmlspecialchars($_POST['composer']);
$instrument = htmlspecialchars($_POST['instrument']); 
$ensemble = htmlspecialchars($_POST['ensemble']);

// Prepare the MySQL query and execute it using prepared statements
$sql_query = "SELECT db_genre, db_composer, db_instrument, db_ensemble FROM recording_metadata
WHERE (CASE WHEN ?='all' THEN true ELSE column=genre END) AND 
      (CASE WHEN ?='all' THEN true ELSE column=composer END) AND 
      (CASE WHEN ?='all' THEN true ELSE column=instrument END) AND 
      (CASE WHEN ?='all' THEN true ELSE column=ensemble END)";  
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con); //$con defined earlier by mysqli_connect
if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql_query)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $genre, $composer, $instrument, $ensemble);
}
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $genre, $composer, $instrument, $ensemble);
```

I only know that the WHERE clause is incorrectly written because some error in it invalidates the execution of the subsequent mysqli_stmt_* commands. I don't know what that error is or how to fix it.

I appreciate if anyone can tell me how to write the WHERE clause that will return the desired rows when one or more parameter value is "all". Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of your usage of `htmlspecialchars` there?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather to vary the statement using PHP instead of MySQL command:

```
// Prepare the WHERE clause using PHP
$genre = htmlspecialchars($_POST['genre']);
$composer = htmlspecialchars($_POST['composer']);
$instrument = htmlspecialchars($_POST['instrument']); 
$ensemble = htmlspecialchars($_POST['ensemble']);

$where = ' 1 = 1';  //First condition which is always true

if ($genre != 'All') {
  $where .= " AND db_genre = $genre"; //Append to the $where variables if genre is not 'All'
}

if ($composer != 'All') {
  $where .= " AND db_composer = $composer";
}

if ($instrument != 'All') {
  $where .= " AND db_instrument = $instrument";
}

if ($ensemble != 'All') {
  $where .= " AND db_ensemble = $ensemble";
}

// Prepare the SQL query based on the variable above
$sql_query = "SELECT db_genre, db_composer, db_instrument, db_ensemble FROM recording_metadata $where";
```

Then, the column query will only included if the input is not 'All'.

Comment: This is a good approach but going from a prepared query to a query which blindly inserts user supplied data is a backward step and opens OP up to SQL injection. You should rewrite the answer using a prepared query.

Comment: Thanks, Ashraf. I see what you did here, and it's a very neat way indeed. But as Nick mentioned, it could lead to SQL injection. I'm hoping to find a more secure way of writing this WHERE clause.

Comment: Hello Nick, how would you rewrite this WHERE clause? Thanks.

Comment: I am quite novice and this sort of prepared-statement is something new for me... thank you for your comment.